# Merge (delete) misspelled [celing-fan] with [ceiling-fan]

Tags: discussion, tags

The [celing-fan] tag i misspelled.

It should be removed and where used instead be replaced by the [ceiling-fan] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.